# Is it possible to give a Xamarin Frame different border colors?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the XAML that I have:

```
<Frame CornerRadius="1" HasShadow="false" Margin="10" 
   BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="Silver" Padding="0" >
```

I saw on the Google Translate that's on iOS that they use something like this kind of a frame to surround different rows in settings. However they have a different border color on the top and bottom.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do the with a frame?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of Google Translate with different border colors?

Comment: Hi Jack, I already did.  It's part of the question.  Note the slightly different color at the base.

Comment: TableView will give you this look and feel out of the box, have you tried it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview

Comment: That's not two colours. That's the frame's bottom shadow!

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that with a component, like this

`BorderEntryComponent.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="X.Y.Z.BorderEntryComponent"

    Spacing="0">
    <BoxView
        x:Name="TopBorder"
        HeightRequest="2"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
    <Entry x:Name="Entry" />
    <BoxView
        x:Name="BottomBorder"
        HeightRequest="2"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

And, in your `BorderEntryComponent.xaml.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace X.Y.Z
{
    public partial class BorderEntryComponent : StackLayout
    {    
        public static readonly BindableProperty TopColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TopColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BorderEntryComponent), default(Color), BindingMode.OneWay);

        public static readonly BindableProperty BottomColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BottomColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BorderEntryComponent), default(Color), BindingMode.OneWay);

        public UnderlineEntryComponent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == TopColorProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                this.TopBorder.Color = TopColor;
            }
            else if (propertyName == BottomColorProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                this.BottomBorder.Color = BottomColor;
            }
        }

        public Color TopColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(TopColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(TopColorProperty, value);
        }

        public Color BottomColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(BottomColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(BottomColorProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you just do this on your .xaml

```
<components:UnderlineEntryComponent
                    TopColor = "Blue"
                    BottomColor = "Black" />
```

You can read more on Bindable Properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you don't have a built in option for what you are looking for.
You could play around by drawing multiple frames on top of each other with different colors and properties, but it is a bit too "hacky" for my taste.

I suggest you create a [Custom Render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) for your own Frame control. This way, you will be able to draw the frame however you want and reuse your control in any other place.